# dns could not translate host name in docker

Tags: django, docker, dns

here is my docker file :

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
MAINTAINER bussiere "bussiere@toto.fr"
EXPOSE 8000
RUN echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
RUN echo "nameserver 80.67.169.12" >> /etc/resolv.conf
RUN echo "nameserver 208.67.222.222" >> /etc/resolv.conf
#RUN echo "dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 80.67.169.12 208.67.222.222" >>  /etc/network/interfaces
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV TZ=Europe/Paris
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-dev build-essential libpq-dev
RUN python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade
RUN python3 -m pip install pipenv
RUN export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
RUN export LANG=C.UTF-8
COPY app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pipenv --python 3.6
RUN pipenv install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["pipenv"]
CMD ["run","python", "manage.py", "collectstatic", "--noinput"]
CMD ["run","python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Here is the error :

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "toto.postgres.database.azure.com" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

with the command :

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 admin_marque
```

When i try to open localhost:8000 in a browser.

The main goal is to deploy it on azure

It's a django app, i know i don't have to user django runserver in prod but i'am ine the process of debugging.

And i'am sure that the url of the database is good.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this issue have less to do with Docker and more (almost entirely) to do with Python? The hostname you are referring to is not specified in the Dockerfile, which leads me to believe it might be an issue with hwo you are building / running your python.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the two `CMD` lines? Only the last would run when you start the container.